# How can I paginate using Resource<T> using Page<T>

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, pagination, spring-data

I am using the following code to create a paginated list of JSON data for `Artist` objects:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/artists/all", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/hal+json"})
public Resources<Artist> getArtists(Pageable pageable) {
    final Page<Artist> allArtists= artistService.GetAllArtists(pageable);

    for (final Artist artist : allArtists) {
        Long artistId = artist.getArtistId();
        Link selfLink = linkTo(methodOn(ArtistController.class).getAllArtistById(artistId)).withSelfRel();
        artist.add(selfLink);
        final Link ordersLink = linkTo(methodOn(MusicController.class).getMusicByArtistId(artistId, pageable)).withRel("musics");
        artist.add(ordersLink);
    }

    Link link =linkTo(ArtistController.class).withSelfRel();
    Resources<Artist> result = new Resources<>(allArtists,link);
    return result;
}
```

The code currently returns outputs that are in this format:

```
{
  "artistId": 2, 
  "name": "Simon Mburu", 
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/artists/2"
    },
    "musics": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/musics/artist/2"
    }
  }
}
```

However my intent is to have the code return an output like this:

```
"pageable": {
  "sort": {
    "sorted": false, 
    "unsorted": true
  },
  "offset": 0,
  "pageSize": 20,
  "pageNumber": 0, 
  "paged": true,
  "unpaged": false
},
"last": true,
"totalPages": 1, 
"totalElements": 2,
"size": 20
"number": 0, 
"numberOfElements": 2
"sort": {
     // ETC...
```

What changes can I make to my code to get it to output the data contained in the above example instead of what it currently outputs?

Comment: What part exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: Hello Paul check the above screenshot of the results of the above code.